# Line Graph data points are being displayed with big distance one from the other

Tags: android, graph, line, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Android Graph library(jjoe64) to display values in line graph. I have managed to display the data points y-Value(Integer) and x-Value(Date). The problem is that my data points are being displayed long one to the other. What I want to achieve is that the data points will be displayed in same distance one from the other. I provide my android app fragment's code. [Line Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZttM.png) - [Collapsing Data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QktL4.png) - [Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lx5h.png)

```
package com.example.drodo.diamondbeacons;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.drodo.diamondbeacons.model.HomeRegion;
import com.example.drodo.diamondbeacons.model.PuckData;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.DefaultLabelFormatter;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GridLabelRenderer;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.LegendRenderer;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.Viewport;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.helper.StaticLabelsFormatter;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPointInterface;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.OnDataPointTapListener;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.Series;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TimelineFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private EditText regionText;
    private TextView timelineDate;
    private Button regionChooseBtn;
    private LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> tempSeries;
    private LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> lightSeries;
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##.###");


    public TimelineFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timeline, container, false);

        regionText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.selectRegionText);
        regionChooseBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.chooseRegionBtn);
        timelineDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timeline_date_view);
        GraphView tempGraph = view.findViewById(R.id.graph);
        GraphView lightGraph = view.findViewById(R.id.graph2);

        tempSeries = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
        lightSeries = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());
        timelineDate.setText(currentDate);

        regionChooseBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            String select_text = regionText.getText().toString();

            if (!select_text.isEmpty()) {

                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

                    firebaseFirestore.collection("PuckData").whereEqualTo("region", select_text)
                            .whereEqualTo("current_date", currentDate).orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                            .get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    timelineDate.append(" - " + select_text);
                                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                                        int light = document.getLong("light").intValue();
                                        int temperature = document.getLong("temperature").intValue();
                                        long millis = document.getDate("timestamp").getTime();
                                        String dateString = android.text.format.DateFormat
                                                .format("MM/dd/yy", new Date(millis)).toString();

                                        tempGraph.addSeries(tempSeries);
                                        tempSeries.appendData(new DataPoint(millis, temperature), true, 250);


                                        tempSeries.setDrawBackground(true);
                                        tempSeries.setAnimated(true);
                                        tempSeries.setDrawDataPoints(true);

                                        tempSeries.setOnDataPointTapListener(new OnDataPointTapListener() {
                                            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                                            @Override
                                            public void onTap(Series series, DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
                                                @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
                                                SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM - HH:mm");
                                                String formatted = format1.format(dataPoint.getX());

                                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.alertDialog);
                                                View alertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.timeline_graph_dialog, null);
                                                TextView tempDialog = alertView.findViewById(R.id.graph_dialog_temp);
                                                TextView dateDialog = alertView.findViewById(R.id.graph_dialog_date);
                                                TextView dialogHeader = alertView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_header);

                                                tempDialog.setText(nf.format(dataPoint.getY()) + " \u2103");
                                                dateDialog.setText(formatted);
                                                dialogHeader.setText(select_text + " Statistics");
                                                builder.setCancelable(true);

                                                builder.setView(alertView);
                                                builder.show();


                                            }
                                        });

                                        Viewport viewport = tempGraph.getViewport();
                                        viewport.setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
                                        viewport.setMinY(0);
                                        viewport.setMaxY(40);
                                        tempGraph.getViewport().setScrollable(true);
                                        tempGraph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsVisible(false);
                                        //tempGraph.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
                                        //tempGraph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelVerticalWidth(20);
                                        //tempGraph.getGridLabelRenderer().setTextSize(20);
                                        //tempGraph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsAngle(90);

                                        lightGraph.addSeries(lightSeries);
                                        //lightSeries.appendData(new DataPoint(date, light), true, 100);

                                        lightSeries.setDrawBackground(true);
                                        lightSeries.setAnimated(true);
                                        lightSeries.setDrawDataPoints(true);

                                        lightSeries.setOnDataPointTapListener(new OnDataPointTapListener() {
                                            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                                            @Override
                                            public void onTap(Series series, DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
                                                @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
                                                SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM - HH:mm");
                                                String formatted = format1.format(dataPoint.getX());

                                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.alertDialog);
                                                View alertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.timeline_graph2_dialog, null);
                                                TextView lightDialog = alertView.findViewById(R.id.graph_dialog_temp);
                                                TextView dialogHeader = alertView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_header);
                                                TextView mainTitle = alertView.findViewById(R.id.main_text);
                                                TextView dateDialog = alertView.findViewById(R.id.graph_dialog_date);

                                                lightDialog.setText(nf.format(dataPoint.getY()) + "%");
                                                mainTitle.setText("Light:");
                                                dateDialog.setText(formatted);
                                                dialogHeader.setText(select_text + " Statistics");

                                                builder.setCancelable(true);
                                                builder.setView(alertView);

                                                builder.show();
                                            }
                                        });

                                        Viewport viewport2 = lightGraph.getViewport();
                                        viewport2.setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
                                        viewport2.setMinY(0);
                                        viewport2.setMaxY(100);

                                        lightGraph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsVisible(false);
                                        lightGraph.getViewport().setScrollable(true);

                                    }

                                } else {
                                    Log.d("PUCK", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                                }
                            });

                }
            }

            regionText.setText("");

            final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
        });
        return view;
    }



}
```

I would like some help in order to solve this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Data points are being plotted according to the values of temperature and light. So, plz tell what points are you storing in database @diamantis.

Comment: As you can see i have 2 graphs, in the first one I want x-values(dates) and y-values(temperature) and in the second x-values(dates) and y values(light). I don't want to display x-axis labels in both graphs.. hope you understand

Comment: Can you plz add your db structure and data.

Comment: Okay I added a picture of my db structure and data. You can check it in post description.

Answer (score 0):

It's not claer what do you want? *What I want to achieve is that the data points will be displayed in same distance one from the other*. Can you add more information? So you want that all points lay through constant dx distance ?

Comment: the last data point as you can see in the photo, is being displayed at the end of the graph where it's not visible to the user.. What can I do to show all the data points to the graph? Hope you understand.. And yes I want them to have same distance!

Comment: I want also to scroll my graph to the right and backwards as well.,But when I scroll to the right my data points are collapsing. Look at picture 2

Comment: As for distance it's very strange question, plot is generate according to data, if you get your points on equals distance so they will display through constant distant. But I don't how you generate data for graph?

Comment: You getting it from data base but what inside it? Can you just display date each hour(day) then it will be at constant distance. As for not fitting view data, at first glance It may be because you set Y bounds (0,40) are you trying to comment this action? How change graph view?

Comment: See the picture in discription "Data Structure" I want to display 2 graphs and in both graphs x values will be dates.. But my graph is displayed in a bit weird way.. I just want all my data point to be shown in equal distance and no x Axis values will be shown...Look at my 3 pictures in description.

Comment: Could you provide me some code? Based on my code please? Thanks in advance. Unfortunately I can't test it now.. I will be able in 4-5 hours.. But you can tell me what to do.. It's urgent!

Comment: Okay. could you provide me some lines of code to achieve that? thanks..

Comment: the code to display bar graph with dates in x axis and temperature in y axis. I want the x axis labels not to be visible and all data points will have same distance one from each other! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i mentioned in comment try to commnet bounds of Y.

```
  //viewport.setMinY(0);
  //viewport.setMaxY(40);
```

As for distance dx, i can't understand why do you need that? May be you should use Bar Cart for that purpose instead Line graph? http://www.android-graphview.org/bar-chart/. Because in Line graph you have restrict dependence between X and Y. You can use your time as signature for your bars.

Comment: I comment bounds of Y but nothing changed.. Any other idea?

Comment: Strange problem, then need to check the data you trying to append to the graph. Write what exact points (x,y) you are geting from DB for first Graph for example, maybe it will get things clear. And as a precaution how you declare graph in XML file?

Comment: I think everything that I have posted so far makes things clear.. I want every DataPoint(x,y) to be (Date, Temperature) where temperature value is integer.. I want to display all data points in the graph with no x-axis labels visible.How difficult is that? And the problem I'm facing is displayed in the three images in my post description. Can't explain it more. Please see my code and if u could test it I would be grateful!

Comment: I can't test it without your data because it may be problem with data points

Comment: Could you please tell me at least how to make two bar graphs instead of line graphs?

Comment: And what a problem? Syntax is just the same i give you a link. Declare private  BarGraphSeries<Data> tempSeries; And then adding your data...think you don't have some problem here

Comment: Okay so you think I'll be alright with my Dates on the x-axis right? Won't i have any problem with data points spacing? Just give an example with dates in x-axis in HH:mm format actually..thanks in advance!